# Expected Expression Error Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, expression

I am running into one error when building my project and I can't seem to find a fix anywhere. The error is showing up on this line: `;:CGFloat = info[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! CGFloat`. Here is my code:

```
func keyBoardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    let info:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()

    let keyboardHeight:CGFloat =  keyboardSize.height - 40

    // Error is on this line
    _;:CGFloat = info[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! CGFloat

    let contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardHeight, 0.0);
    self.tableView.contentInset = contentInsets
    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
}
```

Comment: Just try commenting out the line, it doesnt seem needed. `_;:CGFloat` is not valid swift so its causing the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line where you are getting this problem has syntactical issues. Notice:

```
_;:CGFloat = info[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! CGFloat
```

First, you actually have two statements there, as semicolons break lines. So:

```
_;
:CGFloat = info[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! CGFloat
```

If you break the lines like this you'll now get two errors. The first one says `'_' can only appear in a pattern or on the left side of an assignment`, which makes sense because an underscore by itself accomplishes nothing. You should just delete this part.

The second line is missing a declaration, so the compiler is not being capable of parsing that line into anything that it understands, hence `Expected expression`. You'd want to store the result from that expression somewhere, and you need a declaration for that. You can to this:

```
let someName:CGFloat = info[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! CGFloat
```

Adjust `someName` to fit your needs. I'm assuming that you need the result from that expression for something, even though I don't see it used after the assignment. If you don't need it, just consider removing the whole expression.

Answer (score -2):

It's because the line of code:

```
_;:CGFloat = info[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! CGFloat
```

is not a valid line of code.

Comment: The OP already knows the problem is with this line. The compiler is already telling the OP that it isn't a valid line of code. An answer to this question should explain why it is invalid and how to fix it.